# WDK 10 - Rpcrt4.dll - System Error 2

Tags: c++, dll, driver, wdk, system-error

I have been working with WDK 10 and I have added rpcrt4.lib into the Linker. My driver has been successfully built. When I try to run the driver using command net start mydriver. I get system error 2 message. I tried using dependency walker but I don't see any dll file missing. When I remove the rpcrt4.lib from the Additional Dependencies, I am able to run the driver without any problem. But when I add rpcrt4.lib, it build successfully but on writing net start mydriver it gives system error 2. I need rpcrt4.lib as I am using a function UuidCreate.

I have been working on this issue for last 1 week, but did not find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rpcrt4.dll` is user mode dll and can not be used in kernel space. of course your driver is fail load with code `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND` (which mapped to win32 error `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2) ) - system search registration of `Rpcrt4.dll` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` and not found

for create uuid in kernel mode you need use [`ExUuidCreate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545658(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you know that Rpcrt4.dll is user mode dll. As I don't see anything in msdn that says Rpcrt4.dll is user mode dll.

Comment: @KaushalKumarSingh - strange question.. it used in user mode - special design for support RPC - remote procedure call. PE can not be work both in user and kernel mode. this is xor. then look for example on it import.. you can view that it import from `ntdll.dll`, `kernel32.dll` or `api-ms-*`, `kernelbase.dll` - so if assume that `rpcrt4` worked in kernel - all it dependency's also must work in kernel. so `ntdll` also kernel mode dll ? and at the last read about  [Export Drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542891(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: `Loading an Export Driver

Export drivers must be installed in the %Windir%\System32\Drivers directory` - rpcrt4.dll - not found here